# Confused about expanding a logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Equation is $3^x-2=3^{x-2}$

I end up with $\ln(3^x-2)=x\ln 3 -\ln 9$. How do I expand the left side?

Comment: Don't do ln first, do algebra to get $3^x$ on its own.

Comment: Hint: $$
3^x  - 2 = 3^{x - 2} \Leftrightarrow
 3^x  - 3^{x - 2}  = 2 \Leftrightarrow 3^x \left( {1 - \frac{1}{9}} \right) = 2 \Leftrightarrow 3^x  = \frac{9}{4}
$$

Comment: @Gary doesn't leave the poster with much :(

Comment: Look at my edit to see how i typed the expressions. To learn more look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Gary It is more than a hint.

Comment: @Gary I agree with Paul and VIVID, please, don't solve the problems for them.

Comment: Sorry, I should have left the last bit out.

Comment: @Paul no I understand now, I should've first done algebra to get $3^x$ on its own